# Angular Pagination - pager component

Tags: angular, events, pagination, pager

I created a paging component, to take the user thru pages in a grid. I am trying to use this component on a specific page, but I get the error:

```
'pager' is not a known element:
1. If 'pager' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
</div>

[ERROR ->]<pager  (get-page)="getPage($event)"></pager>
```

What am I doing wrong? I have added this to my app.module too.

```
import { PagerComponent } from './shared/pager.component';
```

Here is my pager component.

html:

```
<div>
    <button (click)="goToPage(1)" [disabled]="pageNumber==1">
        <md-icon>first_page</md-icon>
    </button>
    <button (click)="previous()" [disabled]="pageNumber==1">
        <md-icon>chevron_left</md-icon>
    </button>
    <input #input type="text" style="width: 30px;height:30px" (keyup.enter)="goToPage(input.value)" [(value)]="pageNumber" >

    <button (click)="next()" [disabled]="pageNumber==totalPages">
        <md-icon>chevron_right</md-icon>
    </button>
    <button (click)="goToPage(totalPages)" [disabled]="pageNumber==totalPages">
        <md-icon>last_page</md-icon>
    </button>
    <br />
    Showing page {{pageNumber}} of {{totalPages}} pages.
</div>
```

component:

```
import {Component, Input, EventEmitter, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'pager',
    templateUrl: 'pager.component.html',
    outputs: ['getPage: get-page']
})
export class PagerComponent {
    @Input('total-pages') totalPages: number;
    @Input('total-items') totalItems: number;

    getPage: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    totalPages: number;
    pageNumber: number;

    constructor(){
        this.pageNumber = 1;
    }

    goToPage(page:number){
        this.pageNumber = page;
        this.getPage.emit({
            pageNumber: page
        });
    }

    previous(){
        if(this.pageNumber <= 1 || this.pageNumber > this.totalPages || isNaN(this.pageNumber)) {
            return;
        }
        this.pageNumber = Number(this.pageNumber) - 1;
        this.goToPage(this.pageNumber);
    }

    next(){
        if(this.pageNumber >= this.totalPages || this.pageNumber < 1 || isNaN(this.pageNumber)){
            return;
        }

        this.pageNumber =  Number(this.pageNumber) + 1;
        this.goToPage(this.pageNumber);
    }
}
```

Usage in another component:
html:

```
<pager  (get-page)="getPage($event)"></pager>
```

component:

```
import { PagerComponent } from '../shared/pager.component';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './list.component.html',
    providers: [PagerComponent]
}) 
.....

    getPage(page) {
            this.getItems(page);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You imported the component, but did you declare it?

```
import { PagerComponent } from './shared/pager.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [PagerComponent] 
  // ...
})
```

Also, you shouldn't declare a component in the `providers` array of another component. That's for injected services that get shared at that level.

Comment: In the component where I am using the Pager, I am declaring it as: @Component({
    templateUrl: './list.component.html',
    providers: [PagerComponent]
})

is providers the correct way to do it?

Comment: I don't think it should be in your providers. That's where you declare services that get injected and shared at that level.